# Python import results in a massive flood of debugging texts

Tags: python, import, pytorch

I have a function that is used to load a pytorch model from a pre-trained checkpoint. Here is the full code:

```
import torch
from model import GrooVAEDensity1D

def load_density_1d_model(model_path, params_dict=None, is_evaluating=True, device=None):

    try:
        if device is not None:
            loaded_dict = torch.load(model_path, map_location=device)
        else:
            loaded_dict = torch.load(model_path)
    except:
        loaded_dict = torch.load(model_path, map_location=torch.device('cpu'))


    if params_dict is None:
        if 'params' in loaded_dict:
            params_dict = loaded_dict['params']
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Could not instantiate model as params_dict is not found. "
                            f"Please provide a params_dict either as a json path or as a dictionary")

    if isinstance(params_dict, str):
        import json
        with open(params_dict, 'r') as f:
            params_dict = json.load(f)

    model = GrooVAEDensity1D(params_dict)
    model.load_state_dict(loaded_dict["model_state_dict"])
    if is_evaluating:
        model.eval()

    return model
```

When I try importing this function in another .py file, it goes absolutely insane:

```
from data.src.dataLoaders import GrooveDataSet_Density
from model import GrooVAEDensity1D
from helpers.Control.density_1D_modelLoader import load_density_1d_model
```

When it hits the 3rd line of code, it briefly prints out the following:
`DEBUG:git.cmd.Popen(['git', 'version'], cwd=...etc...)`

And then it starts printing out hundreds upon hundreds of lines of what looks to be debugging text? Here is a small sample:

```
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:==== SSA block analysis pass on 60
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:Running <numba.core.ssa._GatherDefsHandler object at 0x7fa31e6d2130>
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: $60load_global.0 = global(np: <module 'numpy' from '/Users/jlenz/opt/miniconda3/envs/GrooveTransformer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>)
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: $62load_method.1 = getattr(value=$60load_global.0, attr=log2)
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: $68binary_true_divide.4 = num_equal / num_non_zero
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: $70call_method.5 = call $62load_method.1($68binary_true_divide.4, func=$62load_method.1, args=[Var($68binary_true_divide.4, sparse.py:528)], kws=(), vararg=None, varkwarg=None, target=None)
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: $72unary_negative.6 = unary(fn=<built-in function neg>, value=$70call_method.5)
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: $74return_value.7 = cast(value=$72unary_negative.6)
DEBUG:numba.core.ssa:on stmt: return $74return_value.7
```

I looked up similar error messages, tried running in different conda environments, and running individual lines of this code on my system; all without issues.

Answer (score 0):

These are just for debugging, it should run okay if you keep them. But if it's an eyesore for you, [this person appears to be having the same issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5965#issuecomment-664901501). Someone was able to [suppress the messages](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/5965#issuecomment-820951216) by using the following:

```py
import logging
logging.getLogger('numba').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```